# Git list changed files excluding changes line endings

Tags: windows, git, phpstorm, line-endings

I use PhpStorm on Windows. I pulled the sources for a project from a Linux server. Some of these files might have changes compared to the files in the repo. That means, someone might have changed files directly on the server and checked those changes into the repo.

PhpStorm shows 4,000 files as changed, and most of these due to the different line endings, it seems. Changing the line ending in all files to either LF or CRLF is not a solution. Either way, a lot of files are marked as changed.

How can I find all files that actually have code changes? Files where only the line ending has changed should not be included.

Comment: Not a PhpStorm issue. It is standard Git behaviour.

Comment: May be useful, 1. Find all the files with CRLF in the repo, 2. Check if they exhibit Git changes, 3. if they do, convert CRLF to LF: `find . -not -type d -exec file "{}" ";" | grep CRLF | cut -d: -f1 | while read l; do echo -n $l": " ; if ! git diff --exit-code "$l" > /dev/null ; then dos2unix $l; fi; done`

Answer (score 2):

Try git diff --ignore-space-at-eol